# bash expr syntax error when multiplying variable by integer

Tags: bash, osx-yosemite

I am attempting to learn bash, and I tried making a simple bash script to test my terminal. However, when using the expr command, the system keeps telling me that the syntax for the expr command is wrong. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a typo
x=0
y=25
function arrayAndDisplay {
    for x in y;
    do
        typo[x]= `expr $x * 25`
        echo ${typo[x]}
    done
}
arrayAndDisplay
```

When I try running the script in the terminal, this is the error message I get:

```
expr: syntax error
```

I've looked at reference websites and other StackOverflow posts, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me?

P.S: I use Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.1)

Comment: Remove space after `=` and what is the purpose of `for x in y`?

Comment: @anubhava ok, but what do you suggest instead of `for x in y`?

Comment: Btw, `typo[x]=$((x*25))`

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Are you trying to run a loop from `0 to 24`?

Answer (score 2):

The `expr` syntax in mac OS is

```
$(($x*25))
```

rather than

```
`expr $x \* 25`
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` in your `expr` is being expanded, so you're actually passing a list of files rather than a multiplication sign. Escape it:

```
    typo[x]= `expr $x \* 25`
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. `for x in y;` should be `for x in $y;`
2. `typo[x]=`expr $x * 25`` Remove space between left and right of "="
3. `typo[x]=`expr $x * 25`` Remove back ticks as its discouraged and use `$(...)` Alos you should escape "*" as it has a meaning and is expanded to show all the files in current directory. So you should use it like:

   ```
   typo[x]=$(expr $x \* 25)
   ```

Comment: missing the opening `(` in `typo[x]=$(expr $x \* 25)` (＋1) ;)

Comment: Thanks @kobame for bringing it to my notice. Have edited the answer :)